# Core plot xAxis visibleRange start other than 0 disappear the line from beginning

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am using the below but want to start my x Axis as according to my calculate value but when i add the visibleRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(21) it disappear the line from beginning.Please help me out for the same.

```
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(interval)]);
x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");

x.minorTicksPerInterval = 2;

NSArray *exclusionRanges = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.01) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.02)], 
                            [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.00) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.02)],
                            [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.00) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.02)],
                            nil];

x.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
x.labelExclusionRanges = exclusionRanges;
x.titleOffset = 10.0;

x.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(endPoint)];
```

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Eric   where we display x Axix labels above on these labels. Please help out.

Answer (score 2):

The `labelExclusionRanges` removes tick marks and axis labels in the given ranges. You're removing the tick at zero (0). You should just leave `labelExclusionRanges` at nil (its default value) if you don't need that feature.

Comment: Hi Eric, Thanks for your info but my problem is still there.You can see my problem in screen shot at below link http://67.207.132.104/graph.png

Comment: That's correct for a visible range that starts at 21. The parts of the axis outside the visible range—the axis line, tick marks, and labels—won't be drawn.

Comment: x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(interval/2)]);
    //x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    
    //x.minorTicksPerInterval = 2;
    
  
    x.titleOffset = 10.0;
    
    x.labelExclusionRanges = nil;
    x.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(startPoint) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(endPoint)];

Comment: Now my code is like above but facing the same problem Please Eric help me out i have to submit app in morning

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: coridinate plate satrt from 0,0 axis with 21